# To GIVE BIRTH in passive mode

Tags: passive-voice

I'd need help from native english people to understand if and how the verb "to give birth" can be used in a passive form.
I have this phrase but I'm not sure it's ok.
**"They pray for help from idols given birth to by frightened minds."**
I've read somewhere on the web that the passive form must have the "to be" + "past participle" + "to".
now I miss the to be in the phrase but not sure how to use it in the right way.
Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**
First of all I wanna say thanks to all of you, who have spent a little time to answer my question. So, what we have here? Well it seems to me that almost each one of you has his own view.
Even my own phrase, that I thought was wrong or incomplete, has its own "supporter", and even if it is described as non perfect, seems that the same form is quite present on the web.
Than we have some alternative form: Generated by / Birthed by / Born of.
This can be reassumed as follow:

They pray for help from idols,

1. given birth to by frightened minds.
2. generated by frightened minds.
3. birthed by frightened minds.
4. born of frightened minds.

which is a vast array of solution, even if I didn't understand wich one would be the "most correct", if one of them can fall under this kind of definition.
Any other solution and/or further explanation is more than welcome.

Thanks again guys.
I'll follow this thread as long as someone of you keep on adding his point of view.

Cheers.

Comment: Hi Marco, this particular question is trivial for native speakers and such questions are usually off-topic on this site; please consider the [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) (ELL) StackExchange instead.

Comment: @linguisticturn I had to revise my answer after checking for usage.

Comment: Apparently, this question is more interesting to people here than I first thought… Apologies, Marco!

Comment: Your passive *to be* is "there" — it's just reduced from the relative clause along with the relative pronoun: *They pray for help from idols, [who were] given birth to by frightened minds*. That's grammatical enough as passive constructions go. But more natural would be: *They pray for help from idols birthed by frightened minds*. And you don't need the passive voice: *They pray for help from idols born of frightened minds*.

Comment: It is unclear here what would be the active sentence whose passive equivalent is sought. In 'X gave birth', the object is *birth*, so the passive equivalent would be 'birth was given by X' (although it is difficult to imagine the circumstances in which it would be natural to say something like that). In the given example, 'given birth to by frightened minds' does not contain any form of *to be* because it is not a complete sentence to begin with.

Comment: @jsw29: The active would be: *They pray for help from idols, whom frightened minds gave birth to.* *Gave birth to* is kind of a phrasal and prepositional verb, where the object of the preposition can be promoted to subject. Similarly . . . Active: *Frightened minds gave birth to idols.* Passive: *Idols were given birth to by frightened minds.* Still, for best results, don't do that.

Answer (score 2):

One way of doing this is to use the verb *bear* for "give birth to"

> 4. *formal, literary*
>    Give birth to (a child)
>
>    > ‘she bore six daughters’
>
> — [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/bear)

This takes the past participle *born* or *borne.*

It's slightly peculiar because for your use it needs the preposition *of* rather than *by:*

> They pray for help from idols, born of frightened minds.

The reason for using *of* is that with *by,* *born/borne* takes its usual meaning of *carried. Of* changes its meaning to the "give birth" sense, as shown in MW's definition for [*born of necessity*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/born%20of%20necessity).

It **may** be better to lose the comma and have "born of frightened minds" as a postpositive adjectival phrase:

> They pray for help from idols born of frightened minds.

... that is, "idols which were born of frightened minds."

Answer (score -1):

No. It may not be ungrammatical, but it sounds clumsy. The multi-word verb (traditionally, phrasal verb) *give birth to* resists undergoing the passive transformation, even though it is transitive. This is especially true when whiz-deletion (here 'which were/are') occurs.

You're better using the past participle of a simplex (not a phrasal) verb here,

- '... generated by frightened minds'

(or even

- '... birthed by passive minds'):

[[Merriam-Webster]((https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/birth)]:

> *birth* [verb] [transitive verb]
>
> 1 chiefly dialectal : to bring forth
>
> 2a: to give rise to
>
> ...

To be fair, there *are* quite a lot of examples of 'was given birth to by ...' on the internet, but not usually in past-participle clauses (ie lacking the 'was'/'were').

Comment: I don't know why you got a couple of downvotes. I don't much like ***birthed*** here, but it's a helluva lot better than trying to shoehorn ***to bear = to give birth to*** into a passive context (which *doesn't* seem to have attracted any downvotes for Andrew! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers That's because it's not necessary to shoehorn it into the passive. I do prefer *born of* to *birthed by* though.

Comment: In the specific (derogatory) context, perhaps it would be better to switch to ***spawned by*** or similar.

Comment: @FF Or conjured [up]. _Downvotes conjured by reactions to comments elsewhere_.

Comment: *comments and idols [**bred of** ignorance*.](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22bred+of+ignorance%22)